# Как определить сделан ли запрос через ajax в корзине?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

На странице корзины отображается одновременно корзина и страница checkout с формой.
Также в коде используется хук `wp`

```
add_action('wp', 'some_actions');
function some_actions(){
    if(is_cart()){

    }else{
        //здесь нужно проверять, чтобы код выполнялся не на странице корзины
        //но сюда попадают и ajax-запросы из корзины
    }
}
```

но проблема в том, что в корзине также выполняются ajax-запросы, и в них также вызывается хук `wp`. В результате тот код, который нужно выполнить за пределами корзины выполняется в ajax-запросе в корзине.
Как проверять ajax-запросы в корзине, т.е. чтобы можно было вызвать нужный код только за пределами корзины?

**P.S.**
добавлю, что товар может добавляться в корзину с дополнительным параметром в get-запросе, т.е. корзина может открываться примерно так: `/cart?param=someValue`. т.е. для некоторых товаров есть get-параметр, а для некоторых нет

Answer (score 1):

На странице checkout я вижу только один ajax-запрос (вы сами можете открыть вкладку Network в dev tools браузера и проверить, что у вас). Отследить этот запрос можно так:

```
add_action( 'wp', 'some_actions' );
function some_actions() {
    if ( is_cart() ) {

    } elseif ( 'update_order_review' === $_GET['wc-ajax'] ) {
        // Здесь выполняется код только в случае ajax-запроса из checkout.
    }
}
```

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста, в корзине network показывает, что срабатывают два ajax-запроса: `/?wc-ajax=get_refreshed_fragments` и `/?wc-ajax=update_order_review`. Если добавить это условие `if (!is_cart() && $_GET['wc-ajax'] !== 'update_order_review' && $_GET['wc-ajax'] !== 'get_refreshed_fragments') {`  он всё-равно выполнится в корзине, а по идее он должен выполняться только за пределами корзины. Скорее всего в это условие попадают и другие get-запросы из корзины

Comment: т.е. нужно в хуке `wp` (или в другом) выполнить код, который выполниться на всех страницах, кроме корзины и кроме checkout

Comment: добавлю, что товар может добавляться в корзину с дополнительным параметром в get-запросе, т.е. корзина может открываться примерно так: `/cart?param=someValue`

Comment: проблема была в том, что отправлялись дополнительные get-запросы, к примеру если не найдена картинка